# What should I install for my print server

Tags: network-printer, cups

I have two standard HP printers in my house - one downstairs, and one upstairs. There is a desktop computer by each of the printers - the upstairs one runs Ubuntu, and the downstairs one runs Windows XP. Both the computers are on different networks with different internet connections.

I want to be able to print to either of these printers from either windows or linux client machines which are on the network.

Anyway, if my description of my setup was a bit rubbish - I basically need to know what printer server software I should use on the Windows XP server machine which will allow both windows and linux clients to print to it. The Ubuntu server is easy - I just use cupsd which is compatible with both, but I don't think you can install cupsd on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUPS speaks SMB and IPP, which means that you can use either the built-in printer sharing, or you can install IPP print server software.

Comment: So if I go on Windows, I just use the default printer sharing options and that will work for linux and windows clients?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I Think one thing to confirm is how are the two computers talking to each other? You said they are on different networks with different connections to the internet?

If you can get a connect pc to pc over your network I would used the basic sharing functionality in windows and connect to the share from the Ubuntu machine.

Hope this helps a little!

James